# Removing an unused overload causes compile error?

Tags: c++, templates, sfinae, overloading, template-argument-deduction

I was looking into removing some unused overloads, and triggered a compile error, which the compiler said was a template substitution error.  But I thought "Substitution Failure Is No An Error", and anyway, why would removing an overload cause it?

Simple beginnings:

```
#include <string>

int ParseInt(const char *);
int ParseInt(std::string);

bool F(int(*)(const char *));

bool User() {
  return F(ParseInt);
}
```

Here, User() is calling F with the address of a parsing routine.  All is well.  ParseInt is overloaded but only one overload matches F's signature.

Enter templated overload of F:

```
bool F(int(*)(const char *));

template <typename T>
struct MetaDeduce {
  typedef typename T::X type;
};

template <typename T>
typename MetaDeduce<T>::type F(const T&);
```

Now there's this weird template overload of F, but it's fine, because function pointers don't have members named X anyway.  Everything compiles, all is well.

UNTIL....

```
#include <string>

int ParseInt(const char *);
// int ParseInt(std::string);  // commenting this out caused a compiler error!

bool F(int(*)(const char *));

template <typename T>
struct MetaDeduce {
  typedef typename T::X type;
};

template <typename T>
typename MetaDeduce<T>::type F(const T&);

bool User() {
  return F(ParseInt);
}
```

As can be seen on godbolt ( http://goo.gl/2Yd04p ), this produces a weird compile error:

```
10 : error: type 'int (const char *)' cannot be used prior to '::'
     because it has no members
typedef typename T::X type;
^
14 : note: in instantiation of template class 'MetaDeduce<int (const char *)>'
     requested here
typename MetaDeduce<T>::type F(const T&);
^
```

WTF???  It looks like the compiler is complaining about substitution failure, but why wasn't that a problem before?  And anyway, I thought substitution failure was not an error!  What's going on?

Answer (score 4):

This is caused by a subtle interaction between two language properties

1. SFINAE only applies in **immediate contexts**. Your `MetaDeduce<T>` is not defined in such an immediate context, and that makes `typename MetaDeduce<T>::type` a hard error. But SFINAE does apply to `typename T::X`, and using that would compile your code even with the `ParseInt(std::string)` overload commented out.

   ```
   template <typename T>
   typename T::X F(const T&);
   ```

[**Live Example**](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/2AOa1FTmQURMbbYO) (note that you get linker errors because you haven't defined your functions)

2. So if the `typename MetaDeduct<T>::type` is the culprit, why did it work with two overloads of `ParseInt`? Well, consider what happens if you would only have the template `F` and both `ParseInt`s. And for convenience sake, give that template `F` a bool return type to ignore for the moment the substitution failure.

   ```
   int ParseInt(const char *);
   int ParseInt(std::string);

   template <typename T>
   bool F(T const&);

   bool User() { return F(ParseInt); } // error, cannot deduce template argument
   ```

[**Live Example**](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/89ixUs6YFpSPIjKx)

With two overloads of `ParseInt` and no extra information in the call `F(ParseInt)`, the compiler cannot deduce which version of `ParseInt` should match the template parameter `T`. In the context of this snippet, this will lead to a hard error (because you will have an empty overload set), but with the extra non-template overload `F(int(*)(const char*))` it would not (because the `ParseInt(const char*)` will match that). Note that because argument-deduction fails here, **the argument substitution would not even take place here in case the return type were `typename MetaDeduce<T>::Type`.**

Effectively, the two overloads of `ParseInt` shielded you from the substitution failure in the non-immediate context. Once you take one of them away, the argument deduction succeeds, and the non-immediate substitution failure leads to a hard error.

It's a bit like crossing a street with a red light, and being saved because two oncoming trucks collide with each other before they could hit you. With only one truck, you are getting hit.

Comment: `typename MetaDeduct<T>::type` in the return type is in the immediate context - if `MetaDeduct` doesn't have a member type called `type`, you get SFINAE. The definition of `MetaDeduct` isn't the immediate context, however, and the error occurs there, so it's a hard error.